# Сдесь и здесь

Tags: орфография

Скажите, пожалуйста, где и как писать это слово? Очень часто путаюсь и меня постоянно спасает Mozilla, объясните пожалуйста правописания этого слова.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Это слово всегда и везде пишется ЗДЕСЬ и значит "в этом месте, в этом случае". Вероятно, вы помните правило, что приставки З- в русском языке нет, есть только приставка С-: *сделать, сдать, сгиб* и т.д.  В слове *здесь* согласная **З** является не приставкой, а частью корня. Если вас интересует происхождение слова, то современная форма *здесь* развилась из прежней *сьдесе* в результате утраты редуцированного *ь*, озвончения *с> з* перед звонким *д* и ослабления безударного *се* в *сь*. Само слово *сьде* образовано из сочетания местоимения *сь* {сей) и элемента *де*, как в слове *где* (По данным Этимологического словаря русского языка Г.П. Цыганенко).